# Find the spec of a localized ring.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I must find the following: $$\operatorname{Spec}\left(\Bbbk[x,y]/\left<xy-1\right>\right)$$
Is there a way to describe that set? I am trying to find the laurent polynomials rings prime ideals. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $k[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong k[x]_x$ (localization) and in general, $\mathrm{Spec}(A_f) \cong D(f)$.